# Do AFJsonRequest and AFHttpClient work together?

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"contact.php"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"companyID", constCompanyID,
                        nil];

NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod: @"POST" path:@"contact.php" parameters:params];


AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    for(id entry in JSON)
    {
        self.strAddr = [entry valueForKeyPath:@"addr"];
        CCLOG(@"Address: %@", self.strAddr);
    }
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
CCLOG(@"Address: %@", strAddr);
```

in the log, address is null. The PHP is fine; in a browser, it returns what I want.

This code worked until I added the AFHTTPClient to pass in a variable. I must be doing something wrong or can I not do it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 1, you're attempting to create a URL from "contact.php" (which `NSURL +URLWithString:` returns `nil` for) when what you really need is the base URL--the full URL that is common among requests for a particular web services, e.g. "http://api.twitter.com/1/".